# Firefox cannot access bookmarks and history on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, history, ubuntu-18.04

[image]

Firefox somehow loses access to its bookmarks and history files **on every reboot**. I tried the following options which solve the problem until I reboot again:

- Followed Mozilla's [troubleshooting guide](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/fix-bookmarks-and-history-will-not-be-functional?redirectlocale=en-US&as=u&redirectslug=The%20bookmarks%20and%20history%20system%20will%20not%20be%20functional&utm_source=inproduct)
- Deleted `/home/username/.mozilla/`
- Deleted `/home/username/.cache/mozilla/`
- Re-installed Firefox

Comment: Read the error message carefully. It tells you what to look for.

Comment: @DavidPostill I ran `lsof` on its `places.sqlite` files and they are not being used by any other processes. What else are you suggesting?